# SELECT inheritance performance: LEFT OUTER JOIN vs "super-table" TYPE COLUMN

Tags: mysql, database, join, left-join

I have SQL tables with inheritance:

- *history* (id, date, ip user_id): the "super-table".
- *history_connection* (id,user_agent): map user's account connections.
- *history_email* (id, email): map user's email modifications.

The goal is to log in my database different kind of history about an user. "id" column of both *history_connection* and *history_email* is a primary key and a foreign key pointing to the *history* table id's.

Now imagine that in a request, I don't need to have access to "sub-tables" columns, but I need to know which type of history it is. Immediately, I think about LEFT OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT h.id,h.date,h.ip,h.user_id,hc.id,he.id
FROM history h
LEFT OUTER JOIN history_connection hc
ON h.id=hc.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN history_email he
ON h.id=he.id
```

If hc.id is not null, I can deduce the type of history: in this case, *connection history*. The problem is I don't think it is very efficient about performance, because if I add a "type" column in the "super-class" *history* I can simplify such query as:

```
SELECT id,date,ip,user_id,type
FROM history
```

My question is, do you think I need to add a type column for performance reason?

Comment: You think about `LEFT OUTER JOIN` but use `INNER JOIN`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, a query that only looks at one table will generally be faster than one that does joins.  But, if your query is like:

```
SELECT h.id, h.date, h.ip, h.user_id, hc.id, he.id
FROM history h LEFT JOIN
     history_connection hc
     ON h.id = hc.id LEFT JOIN
     history_email he
     ON h.id = he.id;
```

Then the performance should be pretty good, under two assumptions:

- You have appropriate indexes (`history_connection(id)` and `history_email(id)`).
- The tables are not too big (namely, they fit in memory).

By comparison, you would have additional overhead for maintaining the `type` column, as you have described it.  You might just consider putting all the extra columns in `history`.  There is small overhead for storing `NULL` values.